# PHP/MYSQL - SELECT FROM WHERE incorrectly matches partial values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that checks if a value already exists in a table on a mysql database. If it does not exist do something, else echo errors.

In my *assessments* table, there is a row named *assessment_code*, which I have populated with records for testing. The structure is below:

**Field:** assessment_code

**Type:** varchar(20)

**Null:** NO

The record entered is ***005-AE1***.

In the script below, I have set $f as a testing value, which will become a $_POST value later. While the variable begins with 005, the error block is echoed despite changing all of the other characters. I even removed the '-' in case it was separating it. Only if I change any of the first three digits does the 'Woooooo!' message appear.

I don't understand why it is assessing the first 3 characters instead of the whole value.

The select script is below:

```
    $f = "005-AE2"; // THIS IS A TESTING VALUE
        // Check if the assessment ID already exists in assessments table
        $query = "SELECT * from assessments WHERE assessment_code=?";

        $q = mysqli_stmt_init($dbconn);
        mysqli_stmt_prepare($q, $query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, 'i', $f);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($q);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($q);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo '<p class="paragraph">'.$row['assessment_code'].'</p>'; // ****This displays 005-AE1****

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) ==0) {

          echo '<h3 class="medium-heading">Woooooo!</h3>';

        // mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else { //  End of Db population
          $error_block = "An assessment with this code exists.";
          echo '<p class="paragraph">'.$assessment_code.'</p>';

          echo '<p class="paragraph error">'.$error_block.'</p>';
        }
```

Thank you,
Lee

Comment: Rows don't generally have names

Comment: @Strawberry?  What?  I usually name them after the Chipmunks.

Comment: Try to not bind the value as integer but as string: `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($q, 's', $f);`

Comment: Thank you @sticky-bit. Gosh, that was so basic to miss. So, 'i' would only check the integers up to the '-'. That makes sense.